# Easiest way to match security groups to their instances in Boto 3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a python list of Security Groups and I need to find to which EC2/RDS instance or ELB they are associated. What's the easiest way to do this in Boto3?

Also, to my best understanding one security group can be attached to several instances and one EC2 instance can have several security groups attached, so I need to find a way to identify those relationships to better clean it up. What I have right is a python list of security group objects.

This is my current code:

```
import boto3
import json

# regions = ["us-east-1","ap-southeast-1","ap-southeast-2","ap-northeast-1","eu-central-1","eu-west-1"]
regions = ["us-east-1"]

uncompliant_security_groups = []

for region in regions:
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)

    sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())

    for sg in sgs:
        for rule in sg.ip_permissions:
            # Check if list of IpRanges is not empty, source ip meets conditions
            if len(rule.get('IpRanges')) > 0 and rule.get('IpRanges')[0]['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0':
                if rule.get('FromPort') == None:
                    uncompliant_security_groups.append(sg)

                if rule.get('FromPort') != None and rule.get('FromPort') < 1024 and rule.get('FromPort') != 80 and rule.get('FromPort') != 443:
                    uncompliant_security_groups.append(sg)


print(uncompliant_security_groups)
print(len(uncompliant_security_groups))

for sec_group in uncompliant_security_groups:
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippets of what you have so far? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Sorry, thought it wouldn't be relevant. I have managed to retrieve the list of security groups as I say, but I have no idea how to compare those uncompliant security groups against EC2/RDS and ELBs to check which resource is using which security group.

Comment: There is no association info in the SG. You need to query your resources for the attached SGs. Then compare that list with all available SGs and determine the unattached SGs. Not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable AWS Config Aggregator in the account (granted you have to pay for it):

```
account_id = '0123456789'
region = 'us-east-2'
sg_id = 'sg-0123456789'
relationship_data = CONFIG_CLIENT.get_aggregate_resource_config(
    ConfigurationAggregatorName='agg_name',
    ResourceIdentifier={
        'SourceAccountId': account_id,
        'SourceRegion': region,
        'ResourceId': sg_id,
        'ResourceType': 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
        }
    )]
    relationship_data = relationship_data['ConfigurationItem']['relationships']
    print(relationship_data)
```

Which should return some data like:

```
[
{'resourceType': 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface', 'resourceId': 'eni-0123456789', 'relationshipName': 'Is associated with NetworkInterface'}, 
{'resourceType': 'AWS::EC2::Instance', 'resourceId': 'i-0123456789', 'relationshipName': 'Is associated with Instance'},
{'resourceType': 'AWS::EC2::VPC', 'resourceId': 'vpc-0123456789', 'relationshipName': 'Is contained in Vpc'}
]
```

NOTE: This appears to ONLY work with AWS CONFIG AGGREGATORS! I have NO idea why this is, or if the data can be obtained from aws config by itself. However my org uses aws config so this enables this type of data for me.
Boto3 config docs:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html